# Failed visualization of bar charts in Nprinting

Tags: qliksense

I am working with NPrinting (power point type) connected to a Qlik Sense app. I inserted stacked charts, but when converting the report into the power point, I came across this situation:

- Either no bars are displayed in the chart ( the values appear as 0).
- It appear only one bar related to one field ( the rest appear as 0).

However, when I right click on the chart in the power point, edit and open the excel all values are displayed in the table, so I don't get why they cannot be visualized  in the chart.

In Qlik sense, I inserted a formula directly in the measure of this type to format the values:

```
= if(SUM([Amount]) > 1000000000,  num(SUM([Amount])/1000000000 , '#,##0.0B'),
if(SUM([Amount])> 1000000,  num(SUM([Amount])/1000000 , '#,##0.0M'),
if(SUM([Amount])> 1000,  num(SUM([Amount])/1000,  '#,##0.0K'),
num(SUM([Amount]), '#,##0.0'))))
```

What can be the issue?

Thanks a lot for your answer!

I've tried to

- Change the formula in Qlik
- refresh the connection in Nprinting
- update the table

However, no improvement so far.

Comment: It could be that since you're using custom formatting for your numbers in Qlik, those values aren't being correctly interpreted as numbers in the Excel/PowerPoint chart. That would explain why you can see the values in the Excel view but not in the actual PowerPoint chart. Can you confirm whether or not the numbers in the Excel view are formatted the way you did it in Qlik? Like '#,##0.0K' etc?

Comment: Yes, the problem it's indeed the fact that the excel interpret the numbers as text. Tried to convert the text into numbers directly in excel but it didn't work. Any other workaround that I can test in Nprinting to keep this kind of formatting (1.5 B or K or M)? I've tried to format numbers in Nprinting through the excel and the ppt labels, but I cannot do a mix of B, M or K.

Answer (score 0):

In Qlik you should be able to modify your expression to look something like this:

```
=Dual(
    if(SUM([Amount]) > 1000000000
      , num(SUM([Amount]) / 1000000000, '#,##0.0B')
      , if(SUM([Amount]) > 1000000
          , num(SUM([Amount]) / 1000000, '#,##0.0M')
          , if(SUM([Amount]) > 1000
              , num(SUM([Amount]) / 1000, '#,##0.0K')
              , num(SUM([Amount]), '#,##0.0'
    ))))
  , SUM([Amount])
)
```

You may need to **Number formatting** option for that field to be `Measure Expression` for it to show up correctly.

The [`Dual()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/FormattingFunctions/Dual.htm) will let you display the field values in specific way, like with custom formatting, but still retain the underlying "pure" numeric value. In your case, it should allow you to display the field values in the custom format you want while still being able to use the underlying "raw" numbers in your nPrinting report.